# Applying a git patch produces an unexpected commit #

Tags: git

I created a patch to send to a co-worker with the git apply-patch command and told him the commit # was 772.. etc. 
He took my patch and applied it using git-am and got a different commit number, I was expecting the same commit #. git log also shows that he did the commit instead of me.

Is this unexpected behavior, and if it is expected -> how can I send him a patch that he can apply retaining the same commit# and have git recognize that it is my commit.

We do not push/pull from a common repo b/c I don't have permission to push to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is expected behavior.

From the git documentation, there are three commands dealing with patches: `format-patch`, `apply-patch` and `am (apply mail)`.

`format-patch` is outbound: It creates a patch that can be applied by someone else. It does contain the headers necessary to recreate that commit completely.

`am` does respect the headers created with `format-patch`.

`apply-patch` however does not!

So whatever has been contained in the patch you applied, it's creator information got lost in YOUR commit because you used `apply-patch`, and it survived the patching when your coworker used `am`. And this is the reason for the difference in the hash.

Comment: thanks. Can you think of a way to have the commit on his computer match mine?

Comment: You commit it, and push it to him, or he pulls it from you. Or you exchange it via a third machine hosting the repository for both of you.

Comment: Or use `git bundle`... Also, even if he used the same name/email, the dates are still likely different, which also influence the hash...